# How to COUNT(DISTINCT a,b) after GROUP BY c

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count

I have a table of three columns: `newspaper`, `person`, `page`.
One person can read a page multiple times which means we might have a table like this:

```
newspaper   person  page
---------   ------  ----
NY Times      A      1
NY Times      A      1
NY Times      A      1
NY Times      A      2
NY Times      B      8
NY Times      B      9
NY Times      B      9
WashPost      A      1
WashPost      B      1
```

I want to `COUNT` for each newspaper (=`GROUP BY newspaper`), the number of times a page is read by someone. To clarify what I mean, for the above input table the result must look like:

```
newspaper     COUNT
---------   --------
NY Times        4   =>  (A,1) (A,2) (B,8) (B,9)
WashPost        2   =>  (A,1) (B,1)
```

My first attempt was the below query which is not allowed by `sqlite` but clarifies what I need:

```
SELECT newspaper, COUNT(DISTINCT person, page)
FROM T 
GROUP BY newspaper
```

---

As a workaround, I can concatenate `person` and `page` columns using `||` and the query works perfectly, but I was thinking of a better solution.

```
SELECT newspaper, COUNT(DISTINCT person || page)
FROM T 
GROUP BY newspaper
```

Comment: Your method should be fine given your data (newspapers don't generally have numbers in their names).  I would add in a delimiter, such as `:` or `~` between the two values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff As the accepted answer is also suggesting, it's better to avoid the "concatenate" way. And btw, the correct solution is straightforward and neat.

Comment: . . There is nothing wrong with the string concatenation (it would be better if `count(distinct)` supported multiple columns).  Your query is quite simple.  Try a query with multiple `count(distinct)` and other aggregations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `distinct` to get rid of duplicates and then `count(*)` rows for each newspaper. For this purpose we use subquery:

```
select newspaper, count(*) as reads_no
from (
  select distinct newspaper, person, page
  from t
) t
group by newspaper
```

You shouldnt concatenate two fields and make a distinct out of it because unless used with some crazy delimiter that you know will never exist within fields you could discard some values. See the below example.

```
'aab' || 'xzy' = 'aa' || 'bxzy'
```